# PHP debug configuration hangs - Waiting for XDebug session | Eclipse (Mars)

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu, xdebug

I Configure the Xdebug and connect with eclipse .

When i start debugging, its go to 78% of debugging, and waiting for xDebug Session.

What is wrong with that ?

If need to set Session mean, How ?

Comment: it's not enough information.. I guess, that you have no line `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` in your `xdebug.ini`. May be it will helps.

Comment: ya, already i set that.

Comment: Nope...But i make it work with phpstrom by remove its port and set same localhost address(ip) in phpstrom server and xdebug.ini.

Thank Q !