# XAMPP Eclipse PHP XDEBUG : Waiting for XDebug session

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, xdebug

Problems Launching Xdebug debugger in Eclipse hangs at 78%. 3 hours of testing and still no closer.

**Configuration: Windows 10, XAMPP 1.8.2 - PHP 7.0.9 (php.ini below)**

**Eclipse: Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600**

The xdebug.dll was recommended by https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

```
zend_extension=C:\xampp-7.0.9\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0rc1-7.0-vc14.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
```

Running phpinfo() I can see xdebug is installed/configured

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.5.0rc1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

```
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9001    9001
```

Windows firewall allows Eclipse (changed to both private and public)

Eclipse configuration:
Xdebug global settings and Debug profile both set at 9001 port.
[image]

When running a debug configuration the browser launches with the correct parameters:

```
xxx.localtest.me/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=14805782647381
```

(NOTE: Both Firefox and IE were tested [as external browsers in Eclipse] with the same results) BUT Eclipse hangs with this message

> Launching: Waiting for XDebug Session...    (Launching Test (78%)

This is where I've been for the afternoon so if anyone can run their eyes over this setup and suggest some things I would be most appreciative.

I've looked around SO:

- [Eclipse, XAMPP, xDebug - waiting for XDebug session - stays in 57%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121672/eclipse-xampp-xdebug-waiting-for-xdebug-session-stays-in-57)
- [PHP debug configuration hangs - Waiting for XDebug session | Eclipse (Mars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341240/php-debug-configuration-hangs-waiting-for-xdebug-session-eclipse-mars)

And others... trying almost every combination under the sun.

This has come off the back of an upgrade from an older XAMPP version with PHP 5.6 that had xdebug installed and working on this box. The Upgrade to PHP 7 is necessary due to dependencies by some newer PHP libraries.

Comment: Xdebug 2.5 RC does not work properly on Windows. Go back to **xdebug 2.4.1** for now -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/40803303/783119

Comment: Thank you LazyOne - This fixed my problem. I did try this as one of the first steps but I used the NTS version (and probably 64bit version but xampp on Win runs as 32bit...) anyway, Thank you for saving me.

Comment: Downgrading from XDebug 2.5 to an earlier version did not solve the issue for me.